# ReactJS - Call parent method from child component and await response from parent

Tags: reactjs

I just started working with ReactJS so I am still getting the hang of it. I need some help with one aspect to which I found no answer. I am trying to call a function in a parent component from a child component, but I also want to receive an answer from the parent, containing some data. How can I achieve that?
Currently what I am doing is:

```
import Parent from './parent.js';
class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        };

    click = () => {
        this.props.parentMethod();
    }

    render() {
          <div onClick={this.click}>Hello Child</div>
    }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        };

    someMethod() {
        console.log('bar');
    }

    render() {
          <Child parentMethod={this.someMethod}>Hello Parent, {this.props.children}</Child>
    }
}
```

Comment: "but I also want to receive an answer from the parent, containing some data". You could return something from `someMethod` and put that returned value in a variable in `click`. If you can give this data from the parent to the child with props instead, that would probably be preferable.

Comment: the idea is that I want to update the child (which will be a table) based on the response from the parent. this request to the parent component is meant for DB requests.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I think a better approach would be to set the request response data in your parent state and pass that down to the child as props.

Comment: Can you please show me how to do that without rerendering the child component?

Comment: The child will be re-rendered because its props will be changed, but that is not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't normally do this. Data flows from parent » child in React. Thus, if executing a function on `Parent` changes data passed to `Child`, your `Child` component would re-render.

Using your example:

```js
class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    <div onClick={this.props.changeName}>
      Hello, {this.props.displayName}
    </div>
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    this.state = {
      name: "Bob",
    }
  }

  changeName = () => {
    this.setState({ name: "Sally" })
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <Child
        changeName={this.changeName}
        displayName={this.state.name}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

In this, clicking on the `div` inside `Child` would change the `name` property of `Parent`'s `state`, which would then be passed to `Child` and get re-rendered.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the data on your parent component's state and pass it to children. After calling your function this data changes in the parent, then goes back to child again. By the way, you are missing `return`s in your `render` methods. Look for it.

```js
const Child = ( props ) => {
  const click = () => {
    props.parentMethod();
  }
    
  return (
      <div onClick={click}>
          Hello, this is Child.
          Data is now: {!props.data ? "No data yet!" : props.data }
      </div>
    );
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: "",
  }
 
  someMethod = () =>
    this.setState({ data: "bar"});

  render() {
    return (
      <Child data={this.state.data} parentMethod={this.someMethod} />
    );
    
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```